# How to get the count of string 2 occurrence in string 1 without php built-in functions

Tags: php, string, count

How to get the count of string 2 occurrence in string 1 without php built-in functions.

Example:

```
$strone = "Arun sukumar";
$strtwo = "a";

//Expected Output: 2


$strone = "Arun sukumar";
$strtwo = "uk";

//Expected Output: 1
```

I need to get the count without using any php built-in functions.

This is the question asked in a interview, is there any logic in that?

Comment: looping througn chars comes to mind...

Comment: Don't want to use built-in PHP functions? Don't use PHP.

Comment: This was the question asked in a interview.......... I wonder is there any logic behind it?

Comment: Yes this is a homework question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$strone = 'arun sukumar';
$strtwo = 'a';

echo parsestr($strone, $strtwo);

function parsestr($strone, $strtwo)
{
    $len = 0;
    while ($strtwo{$len} != '') {
        $len++;
    }

    $nr = 0;

    while ($strone{$nr} != '')
    {
        if($strone{$nr} != ' ')
        {
            $data[$nr] = $strone{$nr};
        }
        $nr++;
    }

    $newdata = $data;

    if($len > 1)
    {
        $newdata = array();
        $j = 0;
        foreach($data as $val)
        {
            $str .= $val;
            if($j == ($len -1))
            {
                $newdata[] = $str;
                $str = '';
                $j = 0;
            }
            else
                $j++;
        }
    }
    $i = 0;

    foreach($newdata as $val)
    {
        if($val == $strtwo)
        {
            $i++;
        }
    }
    return $i;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to take your needle, get the first char.. then iterate over each char of the haystack until you get match. Then take the next char of needle and check the next char of the haystack for a match... continue until you have the complete match for needle or until you fial to match a char.

hint: you can access the individual chars of a string by index with `$string{0}` where `0` is the zero based index of the char in the string.

Comment: Can you brief with a example for the above question

Comment: `$string{0}` is deprecated you should use `$string[0]`

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
$string = 'Arun sukumar'; 

$sub_string = 'a';

$count = 0;
for($i=0;$i < strlen($string); $i++){

    $flag = 0;
    $j=0;
    if(strtolower($string[$i]) == $sub_string[$j])
    {
        //echo "match";
        $flag = 1;
        $k = $i;
        for(;$j< strlen($sub_string); $j++){//echo "[".$j . $k."] $count $flag";
            if(strtolower($string[$k]) != $sub_string[$j]){
                $flag = 0;
                break;
            }
            $k++;
        }//echo "<br> $flag";
    }
    if($flag == 1){
        $count++;
        $flag = 0;
    }
}

echo $count;

?>
```

Comment: Whilst this code snippet is welcome, and may provide some help, it would be [greatly improved if it included an explanation](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762) of *how* and *why* this solves the problem. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, not just the person asking now!  Please [edit] your answer to add explanation, and give an indication of what limitations and assumptions apply.

Comment: Thank you @TobySpeight. I am new for stackoverflow. I want to know regarding the explanation, Should I add comments in the code?

Comment: It's best to write an introductory description, and only comment the code as you would if writing it for yourself.  It appears that your answer is showing how to iterate over the string, performing a comparison at each index, so that could be the start of an explanation.  If I'm wrong about that, then describing how I'm wrong will be perfect!

Comment: Thanks @TobySpeight

Answer (score -1):

Not sure why you would not want to use the built-in PHP functions since they would be faster, but something like this would work:

```
<?php
$haystack = 'Arun sukumar';
$needle = 'a';

// you seem to want a case insensitive search, so do a strtolower first
$haystack = strtolower($haystack);
$hitCount = 0;
for ($i = 0; $i < strlen($haystack); ++$i) {
    if ($needle === substr($haystack, $i, strlen($needle))) {
        $hitCount++;
    }
}
echo 'Output: ' . $hitCount;
?>
```

Comment: Of course, `strtolower`, `strlen`, and `substr` are built-in PHP functions.

Comment: What the OP is looking for isn't possible. He will have to use at least 2 of the built-in functions to achieve his goal. He could use just strtolower, if he wants to have dozens and dozens of lines.

Comment: @Dark: no you can do it with basic language constructs. It just makes no sense to do it that way.. well other than an academic exercise.

Comment: I need it without any built-in functions. this was asked in a interview, Any answer for it?

Comment: @Dark: One could iterate over the string. Empty indexes will return `"\0"`, so no need for strlen. And strtolower can be replaced by an `if/chr(ord($c)&0xDF)`. Quite pointless nonetheless.

Comment: Wow do I feel embarrassed. I just thought of not using `substr_count()` since it would do everything for you, forgot about the other methods I'd be using. **sigh**